# "How to fix 'at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>' error in selenium"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have created the object of Select in selenium to handle dropdown . Also have included the associated packages. Yet the dropdown is not getting selected. Kindly help!

**Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/header[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]")));
select.selectByValue("Blouses");**

I am recieving the following error "at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:48)";

Alongwith a note when i hover over Select -

**org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your XPath expression ends with `a` which indicates [`<a>` HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) which in its turn stands for a [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)

In order to be able to use [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class you need to pass to it's constructor a [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) instance which will point to a [`<select>` HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

If there is no `<select>` elements in your page source code - it means that the dropdown is being generated by means of [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) therefore you just need to click the link with the `Blouses` text which in its turn can be as simple as:

```
driver.findElementByLinkText("Blouses").click()
```

If you still want to use XPath - be aware that you can make it a lot shorter, readable and reliable: limit your search scope to hyperlinks only like `//a` and utilise [`text()` XPath function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=55281024) to match only "interesting" links, the expression which will click the link with `Blouses` text would be something like:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//a[text()='Blouses']").click();
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try out this.